# p-adic galois representation and Baire theorem - question about a proof

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations

Let $G_\mathbf{Q}$ denote the absolute Galois group of $\mathbf{Q}$. I'm trying to understand the proof that image of any continuous homomorphism $G_\mathbf{Q}\rightarrow\mathrm{GL}_n(\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_p)$ has image in $\mathrm{GL}_n(E)$ for some field $E$ finite dimension over $\mathbf{Q}_p$. The proof uses Baire theorem and elsewhere on MSE someone said it works with $G_\mathbf{Q}$ replaced by any profinite group. Here is the proof in notes by Conti:

The part I don't understand has the ???. How are we applying Baire's theorem to get the result? My guess was that for some reason $\rho(G)$ is not nowhere  dense - meaning its closure (it's already closed by the way) contains an open set, but I couldn't figure out why that must be true  - and the trivial representation shows it is not true (but the  trivial representation takes values in $\mathbf{Q}_p$  already, of course).
[image]

Comment: There is a typo - it should say an open subset of $\rho(G)$ not an open subset of $E$. Does that help?

Comment: The reason this argument works for any profinite group is that relies on: $G$ being compact to apply Baire's theorem; the fact that open subgroups of $\rho(G)$ have finite index.

Comment: @Mathmo123 thanks for pointing out the typo. I think I now see the argument -  $GL_n(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p)$ is expressed as  a countable union, and since $GL_n(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p)$ (like  every set)  is not  nowhere dense in itself, we see via Baire that not all the  $GL_n(E)$ can be nowhere dense in $GL_n(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p)$, so there must be some $GL_n(E)$ with an open subset. Thanks!

Comment: If you replace $\mathrm{GL}_n(\overline{\mathbb Q}_p)$ by $\rho(G)$, then your argument is correct!